# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm trying to use a **ListView** in a **fragment**. But i get this Error: **FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class**. 
My Code:

My ListFragment:

```
public class whitelist_list extends ListFragment {


    Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        mContext = activity;
        Log.i("Event", "onAttach called");
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.whitelist_content, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Do something with the data
    }

}
```

```
whitelist_list newFragment = new whitelist_list();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment)
.commit();
```

Edit:
Solution: Declare Listview with android:id="@id/android:list"

Comment: if you have ListView in layout then make sure you have declare ListView with `android:id="@id/android:list"` id

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you use a ListActivity/Fragment, the id for your ListView in your layout should be @android:id/list, so:
 In your whitelist_list.xml (whatever_activityname.xml) in your ListView change the id to android:id="@android:id/list"

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error a while back.  For some reason the XML for the layout had been modified so that one of the components had the wrong type.  Go into the xml and look for the  'android.R.id.list' that doesn't belong to that item.  I don't know how it got changed, but I think perhaps that when using the GUI editor, I changed something to list that shouldn't have been.     If you don't see it, post the layout

Comment: That helped me. But I had two ListFragments, with two layout files which each needed the ListView with the id `@android:id/list`. I changed my ListFragment back to a normal Fragment in one file and added the ListView myself.