# Loading ListView fragment fails

Tags: android-listview, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I have a fragment transaction which is not working. My activity (SearchActivity) shows an alert dialog fragment, which when the user clicks yes or no (positive/negative), an onClickListener is implemented within SearchActivity. Within the overridden method, I create a fragment transaction to load a list fragment. However, when I click the dialog buttons, my app crashes. The error log says there is an id... which is not a ListView class. Howver, I don't know where this is coming from. Is the manner I go about invoking the new fragment correct? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Search Activity overrides:

```
    @Override
public void onDialogClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
    ResultListFragment rls = new ResultListFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.searchLayout_container,rls);
    ft.addToBackStack("search");
    ft.commit();
}
```

Dialog Fragment:

```
public class MoreIngredientsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
SearchActivity sActivity;

public interface MoreIngredientsDialogListener{
    public void onDialogClick(DialogFragment dialog);
}

MoreIngredientsDialogListener mListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);ce
    try {
        mListener = (MoreIngredientsDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement MoreIngredientsDialogListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Do you have additional ingredient a?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            mListener.onDialogClick(MoreIngredientsDialogFragment.this);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            mListener.onDialogClick(MoreIngredientsDialogFragment.this);
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

List Fragment (ResultListFragment):

```
public class ResultListFragment extends ListFragment {
String[] menuItems = {"beef", "chicken", "pie"};
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menuItems));
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_result, container, false);
    return view;
}
}
```

Error Log:

```
02-20 12:29:57.381    2114-2114/com.ygutstein.neiumasterproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
        at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:402)
        at android.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:203)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:842)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

02-20 12:29:57.421     873-1092/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.ygutstein.neiumasterproject/.SearchActivity
    02-20 12:29:57.431     873-1092/system_process W/WindowManager﹕ Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21020
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to change my ListView in my xml file. Saw the answer here: [android.R.id.list not ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899086/fatal-exception-main-java-lang-runtimeexception-content-has-view-with-id-attri)

Formerly:

```
android:id="@+:id/listView"`
```

New:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```