# calling fragment from activity throws null pointer exception- Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to call a List fragment from fragment activity, I m getting null pointer exception.Here is my code,

```
public class SampleEvents extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_events);
        FragmentManager fm       = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment        fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content); 
        if (fragment == null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, new EventsList());
            ft.commit(); 
        }


    }
```

Layout of fragment activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout of the fragment event_list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_TV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#0c2c0c"
        android:text="No Announcements Found"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/events_list"
         android:padding="10dip"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
     </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment class

```
public class EventsList extends ListFragment  implements
android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    View rootView;
    static SharedPreferences sPrefs;
    private NetWorkConnection nc;
    private BaseAlerts alert;
    private ListView events_listview;
    private TextView emptyTV;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_list, container, false);
        initUI();
        uiListener();
        return rootView;
}
```

Whats wrong with my code?Can someone help?

The log cat

```
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ie.minoritybussiness/com.ie.minoritybussiness.dashboard.SampleEvents}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:402)
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:203)
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:843)
06-10 19:22:08.248: E/AndroidRuntime(1009):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
```

Comment: Post your logcat here please!!!

Comment: try this  `ft.add(R.id.fragment_content,fragment);` add `Fragment` as second argument and also refer @Zorn answer's

Comment: Where is the NPE occurring?

Comment: @Jonathan added log cat

Comment: Your error is in the fragment's layout xml or the fragment itself, and not in the activity. You should post them.

Comment: @Zhuinden I have posted the code,Pls take a look

Comment: You should accept jacobhyphenated's answer after changing the         android:id="@+id/events_list" to android:id="@android:id/list" . It should work.

Comment: @Zhuinden Changing that also gives me the same exception , should i change the id of listview or the file name itself..M sorry.. Im new to android

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi change the id of the list view. It needs to be `android:id="@android:id/list"` for the ListFragment to pick it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class

That looks like your issue. There are 2 reasons I can think of for this to be occuring.

1. You are giving the android id to a non-list view. Check out your XML files for anywhere you are using `@android:id/list` as an id for a view. Rename it to something else.
2. You are using a `ListFragment`/`ListActivity` and are **not** defining a view with `@android:id/list` as the id. These classes require that identifier. See [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899086/fatal-exception-main-java-lang-runtimeexception-content-has-view-with-id-attri) for some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

instead of:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

**Edit:**
If you are not using support library than this is probably not the reason for exception. I will give you example how do i do it:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

Fragment fragment = (ListFragment) fragmentManager
            .findFragmentByTag("List");

if (fragment != null) {
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment, fragment, "List").addToBackStack("List")
        .commit();
}
```

So, i am not using findFragmentById. I am using findFragmentTag and when i replace (or add) fragment, i put a tag ("List"). ListFragment is custom fragment i created.

Comment: I'm not importing the support library for fragments, I dont want to support versions below 4.0, Do I still need to go for getSupportFragmentManager();

Comment: I have read on stack overflow that the support library fragments are better maintained than the android.app.Fragments, and therefore it's better to use them even if you're not supporting the old versions.